# MFC: How to custom draw a dynamically created CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I need to customize the head/row height of a CListCtrl. After some googling, I know that I need to subclass CListCtrl, so I wrote my own list class, with the outline as follows:

```
class CListCtrlCl : public CListCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CListCtrlCl)

public:
```

...

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListCtrlCl, CListCtrl)
    ON_WM_MEASUREITEM()
    ON_WM_MEASUREITEM_REFLECT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
void CListCtrlCl::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    ModifyStyle(0,LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED);
    CListCtrl::PreSubclassWindow();
    CHeaderCtrl *pHeader = GetHeaderCtrl();
    m_Header.SubclassWindow(pHeader->GetSafeHwnd());
}
void CListCtrlCl::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)
{
    if (m_nRowHeight>0)
    {
        lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = 100;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method worked if I drag a CListCtrl control in dialog template, but if I create this listctrl dynamically, like:

```
BOOL CListCtrlTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CRect rect(7,7,300,300);
this->m_ListCtrl.Create(WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|LVS_REPORT|LVS_ALIGNLEFT|WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, rect, this,IDC_LIST1 + 1);
SetWindowLong(m_ListCtrl.m_hWnd ,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
m_ListCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);                     
::SendMessage(m_ListCtrl.m_hWnd, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

...

Then the customization code just doesn't take effect. Whatever I did, the result listctrl is the standard one without any customization. But I need to create this listctrl dynamically, so could anyone tell me what I need to do to make dynamically created clistctrl customizable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've left off the necessary style for custom drawing when you create the control.  Add [LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774739.aspx).  That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, PreSubclassWindow is only called when you subclass a control. When you createthe control you have also control over the style.

Simply overwrite the virtual Create function and just add the style like you are doing it in the PreSubclassWindow function. Than call the base class. You can also overwrite PreCreateWindow.

But much simpler than using the ownerdraw feature is cusum draw.